# Arranging minipage in different rows

Tags: spacing, graphics, positioning, minipage

I have created following LaTeX document :

```
\documentclass[22pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\if\ifxetex T\else\ifluatex T\else F\fi\fi T%
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\fboxsep=1mm
\fboxrule=1pt

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent \blindtext

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
      \makebox[\textwidth]{\makebox[1.25\textwidth]{%
      \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}
          \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
      \end{minipage}\hfill
      \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}
          \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
      \end{minipage}\hfill
      \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}
          \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
      \end{minipage}}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This generates arrangement of plots as below:

[image]

So with above approach, I am getting all plots in single row. Is there any way to put the 3rd plot in the next row while keeping 1st two plots in the first row.

Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: minipages are positioned by the same line breaker as letters, so normally they would wrap but you have put them in a `\makebox` the main effect of which is to put tex in horizontal, LR, mode where line breaking is disabled and it comes on one line.

Comment: modified my post with `example-image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main function of `\makebox` is to make a horizontal box, preventing line breaking, so mostly you just need to remove that, I added some negative space to allow the images to bleed into the margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}% there is no 22pt option
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% legacy packages \usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\fboxsep=1mm
\fboxrule=1pt

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent \blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]% 
\centering
  \hspace*{-.1\textwidth}%
      \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image.png}
          \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image.png}
          \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image2}
      \end{minipage}%
  \hspace*{-.1\textwidth}%

\bigskip

      \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image.png}
          \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
      \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is perfect. One question though. If I change the expression `\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}` to `\begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}`, I dont see the plots are aligned in centre. Can you please help understand the reason, and what I need to do to make them aligned centrally with `0.65`

Comment: @BrianSmith 2*.65 is 1.3  so you would need to change the negative spaces to -0.15\textwidth  to keep things within \textwidth